# Update Firefox Addon SDK extension files without restart

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building an extension with Firefox's Addon SDK (v1.10). One of the new features of this SDK is the ability to not require a restart when installing / upgrading extensions.

**Problem**

I have noticed that, when performing an upgrade or downgrade from my SDK extension to a different version of my SDK extension without requiring a restart, files in the 'data' folder do not get updated until a restart is performed.

Is this a bug from Mozilla's Addon SDK loader?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, using a very simple example. Can you provide more detail? Is this HTML content that doesn't change, or JS code, or images, or...

Comment: @canuckistani In my extension, I have tested CSS and XML files located inside the data folder that do not get updated until a restart is performed. The CSS is used to style a toolbarbutton and the XML to provide its moz-binding property (to the same toolbarbutton).

Comment: If you're styling chrome content with your CSS then you'll need to give the CSS rules a kick for them to reload.  Meaning once you load your CSS in the browser chrome it won't just reload that until you restart or remove the <style> block and add it back in.  Can you give a link to some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Firefox will not 'reload' *moz-binding* without a browser restart (thanks [@Bryan Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897414/bryan-clark)).

I ended up completely rewriting my UI implementation to stop using bindings (and xml files) and instead dinamically generate the XUL elements and create what the binding used to describe (in xml) without it.

This means that when there is an update, I can just dynamically remove any old XUL elements and re-add the new ones.